# How to stop Java from rounding my numbers so I can solve Problem3

Tags: java, rounding

So I've been doing some Project Euler lately, but for some reason, my code just doesn't work because Java keeps rounding my divsions.

```
public class Problem3 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double max = 0;
    double n = 600851475431.;

    for (double i = 2; i<Math.sqrt(n); i++){
        if (600851475431.%i == 0){
            if (isPrime (i) == true && i>max){
                max = i;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print(max);

}

public static boolean isPrime(double a){
    for (int i= 2; i<Math.sqrt(a); i++){
        if (a%i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

First of all, 600851475431%168887 does not equal 0, but Java keeps thinking it that it does.

Comment: step 1: consider not using floating point types it you want exact arithmetics

Comment: Side note: `if(isPrime (i) == true)` is a bad style. Replace it with `if(isPrime(i))`

Answer (score 1):

Tip: When you need accurate representations of numbers greater than `2^31 - 1`, use `long`. When you need accurate representations of numbers greater than `2^64 - 1`, use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

600851475431 is between `2^39` and `2^41`.

I'll let you make the conclusion.

**edit**
Another tip: `if (600851475431.%i == 0){`
Notice the `.`. This forces the number to be represented as a `double`. You have a variable `n` in there with an **explicitly** defined type. Use that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Java is right

```
  $ dc
    600851475431
    168887
    /
    p
    3557713
    168887
    *
    p
    600851475431
    ^D
  $
```

Since `3557713 * 168887` is exactly `600851475431`, `600851475431 % 168887` is zero.